# Dynamic library linkage issue in Windows

Tags: c++, linker, qt4, dllexport

I have a problem with windows dynamic libraries. I've written a shared widget library in Linux using Qt/C++. Everything is ok and I can link every application against my library. But in Windows same code compiles, but any application can't use it. I'm getting a lot of linker errors of type `undefined reference to ...` which are all implemented in library.

I found that in Windows, symbol table of code is not exported to binary by default. I have to specify which function I want to be visible in final dll. But I can't manage to find a way to doing that.

Following [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html) instructions, I add `Q_DECL_EXPORT` to all class declarations. but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT` to your class declarations, not `Q_DECL_EXPORT`. Also from the link your provided, which you define accordingly.

If you add `Q_DECL_EXPORT`, you tell the compiler to generate code for that class in every module that includes the header, not to expect the class to be exported in another library.

Comment: I was exporting classes which their code is not included in final binary by default. Because the project was a widget library and only have plugin classes not a widget itlelf. I should separate widget library and designer plugin. Thanks